# Hashicorp vault custom plugin unsupported path

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm writing a custom plugin for Hashicorp vault in golang. I created a backend server to handle the plugin requests

```
err := plugin.Serve(&plugin.ServeOpts{
    BackendFactoryFunc: backend.Factory,
    TLSProviderFunc:    tlsProviderFunc,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

In the backend server I registered two paths:

```
func Backend() (*backend, error) {
    var b backend
    b.Backend = &framework.Backend{
        Help: "",
        Paths: framework.PathAppend(
            registerFoo1(&b),
            registerFoo2(&b),
        ),
        PathsSpecial: &logical.Paths{
            SealWrapStorage: []string{
                "foo1/",
                "foo2/",
            },
        },
        Secrets:     []*framework.Secret{},
        BackendType: logical.TypeLogical,
    }
    return &b, nil
}
```

The requests to foo1 are received and handled, but the plugin ignored requests to foo2.

The error message is: `{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* unsupported path\n\n"]}`. The error message raises in different HTTP verbs.

Both paths have their own module inside the package(`foo1.go` and `foo2.go`)

`foo1.go`

```
func registerFoo1(b *backend) []*framework.Path {
    var paths = []*framework.Path{
        foo1(b),
    }
    return paths
}
func (b *backend) foo1(ctx context.Context, req *logical.Request,
data *framework.FieldData) (*logical.Response, error) {
...
name := data.Get("name").(string)
...
}
```

`foo2.go`

```
func registerFoo2(b *backend) []*framework.Path {
    var paths = []*framework.Path{
        foo2(b),
    }
    return paths
}
func (b *backend) foo2(ctx context.Context, req *logical.Request,
data *framework.FieldData) (*logical.Response, error) {
...
var1 := data.Get("name").(string)
anothervar, err := b.getsomedata(ctx, req, address)
    if err != nil {
        b.Logger().Error("cannot get data: ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Definition of `registerFoo2(backend)` has no issues?

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard no issues. the code compiled successfully using makefile.

Comment: I expect we'll need to see the foo1 and foo2 modules. Also, while it certainly seems like the problem is with foo2, have you tried removing foo1 and foo2 separately from the backend to see what happens?

Comment: @lxop I added some basic implementation

Comment: Have you tried removing things from `foo2` until the problem goes away?

Comment: @lxop Yes, I tried. I tried to make `foo2` to print only one line and the problem still occurring.

Comment: So with identical code between `foo1` and `foo2`, the foo2 path still fails? Have you tried other things like swapping the order of registration, swapping which function is used for each path, etc?

Comment: The code doesn't reach it to it even when I'm swapping the order. IT seems that the path is broken and the vault does not recognized that there is a new path.